# Memory Alignment Guarantee

Tags: c++, cross-compiling, memory-alignment

Is the following code *cross-compilable*?

```
struct Foo {
  alignas(1) char c1;
  alignas(1) char c2;
  alignas(4) int i;
};
static_assert(sizeof(Foo) == (sizeof(int) + 4), "No cross-compilable");
```

In other words, is it guaranteed that `sizeof(Foo) == (sizeof(int) + 4)` for whatever architecture/platform?

Comment: Strictly speaking? I would say not. I don't believe the alignment specification negates the option of padding.

Comment: @StoryTeller I took into account `+4` (that is, `+2` for padding).

Comment: Yeah that's the thing. The padding isn't bound, really. Unlikely to exceed that amount you specified, but not really bound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not it is not guaranteed.  This will work on many architectures today, but on a system with 8-byte `int` (aligned on an 8-byte boundary) this won't work.  In that case, though, you should get a compiler diagnostic because you're trying to apply a less strict alignment to an `int`; see [dcl.align].

Comment: Please, could you provide more details on why that does not work on a "8-bytes int arch"?

Comment: @BiagioFesta If an `int` has 8 byte alignment, then the offset of `i` within `Foo` will be 8, and the sizeof(Foo) will be 16.

Comment: You're right! So `alignof(int) + sizeof(int) == sizeof(Foo)` would be correct? (Note: `alignas(4)` for `int` is removed)

Comment: @BiagioFesta Not quite, since `alignof(int)` could be 1.